# Drawing on screen, do I need surface view?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am always confused about this and I need a pointer on how you would do it. If create a an xml layout with multiple imagesview and text view.  And Lets say I want to draw line between two images and move an image along this line. How do I draw this line? I know I can get location of both images view so I have x1,y1 and x2,y2. My problem is with drawing.

Do I need surface view to have the drawing capabilities and loading bitmaps on the screen along the line?

If yes, then I guess I should always surface view to fill the screen and views on top just incase I need to draw which seems kinda wrong?

IF no (I hope thats the answer), then how do I draw lines, or load bitmaps on screen using only X,Y values?

I hope I was able to explain my confusion
Thanks

EDIT: Actually I thougth of a way of explaining my confusion better.
When you create an activity with xml layout you have something like

```
onCreate (){
setContentView(R.id.layout)
}
```

but when you have activity with drawing view you have something like

```
onCreate (){
SurfaceView v = new Surfaceview(this);
setContentView(v)
}
```

My problem is that we have to set the content layout to EITHER xml layout or to be drawing area . What if I want to set it to my xml layout and at the same time I can draw anywhere on the screen (over images view, empty areas, TextViews ..etc)

See my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on what your desired result is and how much flexibility you need.  You can have a look at this android [Animations tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidAnimation/article.html) (the site is down at the time of posting but google has it cached).

If you don't need flexibility, then for your line, you might be able to create a `View` in your xml with an `android:background` fill color and a size that makes it look as you wish.  You could then use an `Animation` on your bitmap's `ImageView` to translate it along the line, and use a listener on said `Animation` to show/hide the various `Views` as necessary at the beginning or end of your `Animation`.

If you need flexibility, the `SurfaceView` is probably your best bet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes I am familiar with animation and thats how I have been achieving what I want. But when I used to code in java SDK, I would have a while loop and repaint the image at verious point. I see I can't do it without surface view here. Howeever it seems like surface view is telling me: "either me or XML layout". This is due to the fact that setcontentview takes only one paramter

Comment: Android's `Animation` class will do the repainting for you if you tell it to translate from point A to point B.